# window.open() opens a blank screen in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-canvas, window.open, todataurl

I checked this same code in Firefox and it works perfectly. In fact, this worked in Chrome a few weeks back, but now I'm just getting a blank screen.

The code is below:

The function triggers on button click.

```
function saving() {
  var saveURL = canvas.toDataURL(); 
  window.open(saveURL, "_blank", "location=0, menubar=0");
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE] ? Do you have some ad-block plugin ?

Comment: yes, I have an ad block plugin, but I disabled it while checking, so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 15):

While it's no longer possible to do this in Chrome, there are workarounds, such as opening a blank document and writing to it.

```
var win = window.open();
win.document.write("<img src='"+canvas.toDataURL()+"'/>");
```

Answer (score 14):

That's because of a recent change in Chrome:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/chrome-58-deprecations#remove_content-initiated_top_frame_navigations_to_data_urls

You cannot open data URLs directly anymore this way for security reasons.

Instead use the workaround proposed by @Savoo [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45997043/351836) in the other answer or use a [download anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) and click it via JavaScript.