# About:blank when opening an image in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, firefox

There is a feature in the app I'm working on that allows a user to open an image in a new window. It's implemented the following way:

```
const link = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAA...';
window.open(link)
```

It works perfectly fine in firefox, but when I do that in chrome it redirects me to an empty page with `about:blank` url? How do I fix that behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this in Chrome by adding a img tag to the new window:

```
const link = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAA...';
var newWindow = window.open();
newWindow.document.write('<img src="' + link + '" />');
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that Chrome has deprecated the opening of links with a "data:" URL.  See [this link from Google for explanation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/chrome-58-deprecations#remove_content-initiated_top_frame_navigations_to_data_urls) and [this answer from a similar stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45997043/6084963) for a workaround solution.  Hope this helps!